# Date difference in different timezones in java

Tags: java, datetime, google-app-engine, timezone, date-difference

I am pragmatically building a nested JSON from a table. Json looks something like this:

```
{"date":"03-16-2018 06:57:02",
 "details":
    [  
        {  
           "motorstate":0,
           "startTime":"03-16-2018 20:41:57",               
        },
        {  
           "motorstate":0,
           "startTime":"03-16-2018 06:57:02",               
        }
     ]
},
{"date":"03-15-2018 08:08:48",
"details":
   [  
        {  
           "motorstate":0,
           "startTime":"03-16-2018 03:53:30",
        }
   ]
}
```

If you look into the above example, the second record:

```
{"date":"03-15-2018 08:08:48",
"details":
   [  
        {  
           "motorstate":0,
           "startTime":"03-16-2018 03:53:30",
        }
   ]
}
```

The dates are mismatching. This is because the date shown here is in IST but actually stored in UTC in my Google Datastore. In UTC, its still 03-15-2018 and not 03-16-2018.

My question is how can we perform a date difference in different timezones other than UTC in Java? The Date.getTime() method always give the difference in UTC and not in local Timezone.

Comment: You can convert your local timezone to UTC format and then send.
Let me know if it works

Comment: Why should i convert it to UTC, the method Date.getTime() already returns the result in UTC and not local time zone.. which always return 03-15-2018 where my local date is 03-16-2018, that creates a problem in my logic since i am building this nested json based on the day of the date. Please note the time 03:53:30 which is less than 05:30:00 (IST time).. so the date return is always 03-15-2018 and not 03-16-2018

Comment: Try specifying your timezone to the date you are setting and then check.

Comment: pasted the code. below

Comment: Your Question and Title meanders. Can you edit to be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

> Date difference in different timezones in java

```
Period.between(
    LocalDateTime.parse(
         "03-15-2018 08:08:48" , 
         DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( “MM-dd-uuuu HH:mm:ss” )
    )
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( ”Asia/Kolkata" )  ) 
    .toLocalDate()
    ,
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( ”Asia/Kolkata" ) )
)
```

## Details

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome old me old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`.

Tip: Avoid custom formatting patterns when serializing date-time values to text. Use standard ISO 8601 formats only.

Tip: when exchanging date-time values as text, always include an indicator of the offset-from-UTC and the time zone name.

First, parse your input strings as `LocalDateTime` because they lack any indication of offset or zone.

Define a formatting pattern to match input.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( “MM-dd-uuuu HH:mm:ss” ) ;
```

Parse.

```
String input = "03-15-2018 08:08:48" ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

You claim to know that these inputs were intended to represent a moment in India time. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( ”Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

To get the date-only value, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

To represent the delta between dates as a number of years, months, and days unattached to the timeline, use `Period`.

```
Period p = Period.between( ldt , LocalDate.now( z ) ) ;
```

For a count of total days.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below method will return you your UTC time to current Timezone and this worked for me

```
  public static Date getLocalDateObjFromUTC(String date, String time) throws ParseException {
    String dateAndTimeInUTC = date + " " + time;
    SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    localDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date dateInLocalTimeZone = localDateFormat.parse(dateAndTimeInUTC);
    return dateInLocalTimeZone;
}
```

Comment: This converts Local to UTC, i am looking to convert UTC to Local and then perform a date difference. Please understand the question.

Comment: Can you post your code where you are trying to do so or else try setting your
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

Comment: done... check the code after statement    if(pe!=null)

Comment: You need to mention that the timezone you are getting is UTC not IST. It will convert it to your local time automattically after parsing.

Comment: Thanks ! this method will return an object in Date format. If i call the method .getTime() of this Date object, it will always return UTC time in long format. My problem is not conversion, but date difference after conversion..

Comment: The troublesome classes used here became legacy years ago, now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getSummary(String deviceGuid)
{
    Query<com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity> query 
        = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
            .setKind("sensordata")
            .setFilter(PropertyFilter.eq("deviceguid", deviceGuid))
            .setOrderBy(OrderBy.desc("startTime"))
            .build();

    QueryResults<com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity> resultList = 
  datastore.run(query);
    if(!resultList.hasNext())
    {           
        log.warning("No record found..");
        return "No record found";
    }

    com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity e =null;
    com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity pe =null;

    SensorDataOut sensorDataOut = new SensorDataOut();
    SensorSummaryDataOut summary = new SensorSummaryDataOut();
    TotalSummaryDataOut totalSummary = new TotalSummaryDataOut();


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));


    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    //sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));



    long stopTime;
    long startTime;
    long pStartTime;
    long diffTime;
    long diffDay;
    Date pDateWithoutTime;
    Date eDateWithoutTime;

    while(resultList.hasNext())
    {
        e = resultList.next();

        startTime  = (e.contains("startTime"))?e.getTimestamp("startTime").toSqlTimestamp().getTime():0;
        stopTime  = (e.contains("stopTime"))?e.getTimestamp("stopTime").toSqlTimestamp().getTime():0;   
        //log.info("Start Date : " + e.getTimestamp("startTime").toString() + " - " +  String.valueOf(startTime));
        //log.info("Stop Date : " + e.getTimestamp("stopTime").toString() + " - " + String.valueOf(stopTime));
        //log.info("Usage Volume :" + String.valueOf(e.getLong("usageVolume")));

        sensorDataOut = new SensorDataOut();

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(stopTime);                                             
        sensorDataOut.stopTime = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(startTime);                                    
        sensorDataOut.startTime = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());


        sensorDataOut.motorstate    = (e.contains("motorstate"))?(int)e.getLong("motorstate"):-1;
        sensorDataOut.startVolume   = (e.contains("startVolume"))?(int)e.getLong("startVolume"):-1;
        sensorDataOut.stopVolume    = (e.contains("stopVolume"))?(int)e.getLong("stopVolume"):-1;
        sensorDataOut.usageTime     = (e.contains("usageTime"))?e.getLong("usageTime"):-1;
        sensorDataOut.usageVolume   = (e.contains("usageVolume"))?(int)e.getLong("usageVolume"):-1;

        if(pe!=null)
        {               
            //Get the date difference in terms of days. If it is same day then add the volume consumed
            pStartTime= pe.getTimestamp("startTime").toSqlTimestamp().getTime();
            try{
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(pStartTime);
                pDateWithoutTime = sdf1.parse(sdf1.format(calendar.getTime()));

                calendar1.setTimeInMillis(e.getTimestamp("startTime").toSqlTimestamp().getTime());
                eDateWithoutTime = sdf1.parse(sdf1.format(calendar1.getTime()));    


            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                log.info("Exception while parsing date");
                continue;
            }


            diffTime = Math.abs(pDateWithoutTime.getTime() - eDateWithoutTime.getTime());
            diffDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


            //log.info("pDateWithoutTime: " + pDateWithoutTime +  ", eDateWithoutTime: " + eDateWithoutTime + ", consumedVolume: " 
            //          + sensorDataOut.usageVolume;


            if(diffDay!=0) //If not same day
            {
                totalSummary.totVolume = totalSummary.totVolume + summary.totVolume;
                totalSummary.totDuration = totalSummary.totDuration + summary.totDuration;                  
                totalSummary.details.add(summary);
                summary = new SensorSummaryDataOut();                   
            }

        }

        summary.date = sensorDataOut.startTime;         
        summary.totVolume = summary.totVolume + sensorDataOut.usageVolume;
        summary.totDuration = summary.totDuration + sensorDataOut.usageTime;            
        summary.details.add(sensorDataOut);

        pe = e;
    }

    if(summary.details.size()>0)
    {
        totalSummary.totVolume = totalSummary.totVolume + summary.totVolume;
        totalSummary.totDuration = totalSummary.totDuration + summary.totDuration;                  
        totalSummary.details.add(summary);
        summary = new SensorSummaryDataOut();                   
    }

    totalSummary.avgVolume = totalSummary.totVolume/totalSummary.details.size();
    totalSummary.deviceguid = deviceGuid;

    String json = "";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    json = gson.toJson(totalSummary);
    return json;

} //End of Function
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).